# title() method from string in python does not give the correct output

Tags: python, string

`title()` method from string is used to capitalise the first character of each word in string.

For ex.
`"abc def".title()` produces `"Abc Def"` as output.

I tried 
`"1 w 2 r 3g".title()` it suppose to give `"1 W 2 R 3g"` as output but I am getting `'1 W 2 R 3G'`

Can anyone explain?

Comment: [*"definition of a word as groups of consecutive letters"*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title), so `g` is a word.

Comment: ```3g``` is a word so output should be ```3g``` not `3G` because `3` is a first character of word.

Comment: 3 isn't a *letter*, so isn't part of the consecutive group.

Comment: Return a titlecased version of the string where words start with an uppercase character and the remaining characters are lowercase. (from python docs). so `3` is first character because `"1 W 2 R 3g"` is a string and `3g` is a word from the string.

Comment: No, 3g isn't a word. 3 is a number, not a letter, and words are groups of consecutive *letters*.

Comment: sorry I didn't get it. Please you elaborate more.

Comment: I don't have anything to add. That's what the docs say. They also suggest an alternative you could adapt when the algorithm doesn't fit your needs.